# OAuthorizer for Thunderbird Extensions

Tags: oauth, thunderbird-addon

I am about to build an extension where every user has
to grant access on his [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) account.

I am a bit confused about all this authorization thing, 
so I would be glad if someone could give me any advice
about if I can use `OAuthorizer` on this extension or
whatever he thinks is good to know about it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using OAuthorizer, but I recommend you look into alternatives (and report back if you find them!).

I am using OAuthorizer in [version 1.9](https://github.com/mattflaschen/goo.gl-lite) of my goo.gl lite extension.

When 1.9 was reviewed, the reviewer expressed concern that I was including another extension within my own (as well as a secondary issue with synchronous HTTP requests within OAuthorizer). I have not resolved these issues yet myself.

Ideally, extension authors could just specify an OAuth library as a dependency, and it would be installed automatically, without requiring copying the library in, or multiple copies if the user had multiple OAuth-using extensions.

In the meantime, "copy it in" is the only option I'm aware of.

Another issue is that OAuthorizer does not seem to be actively developed.  The last commit of [mozilla/oauthorizer](https://github.com/mozilla/oauthorizer/) was on Jan 23, 2012.  There may be a better or more actively developed library out there.